# 'airodump-ng' not scanning connected devices

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, kali-linux

When running airodump-ng on my router with

```
airodump-ng --channel 1 --bssid (bssid) wlan0mon
```

It fails to scan any of the connected devices on my network even though I am connected to a router that also has another device connected. Both devices are in the same room. I'm running Kali Linux installed on a MacBook Pro; dual booting with OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem years ago and it was that the wireless card of my notebook wasn't able to be switched to monitor mode.

Search for your particular wireless card in the forum of aircrack-ng to be sure about compatibility.

https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatible_cards

Comment: I have previously been able to use it correctly, my card can scan APs but not the associated devices